# How to create React hooks that forward dependencies

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Suppose I wanted to create a React Hook that's like `useEffect`, but it only runs when all the dependencies are non-null. It looks like this:

```
const useNonNullEffect = (callback: () => void, deps: any[]) => useEffect(() => {
    if(deps.every(dep => dep !== null)) callback()
}, deps)
```

However, this fails to pass the "strict dependency" linter:

- It sees `callback` as an undeclared dependency.
- I can't parse `deps`, since it's not an array literal.

Is there some way to create hooks like this, where I take a set of dependencies from the user and forward them to the "real" hook?

(My actual use case is more complicated, this is just a simple expression of the problem for Stack Overflow purposes)

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with your code, this is just an intentional limitation of the static analysis performed by the exhaustive-deps lint rule. To my knowledge all cases where you try to dynamically pass dependencies will throw this warning, including using spread syntax, because dynamic and non-liiteral arrays are not exhaustive. If you know what you're doing, however you can add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` right before the line where `deps` is and the warning should go away.

Comment: Yeah; my question is if there are any more semantic solutions– that is, if there's a way to make the linter aware of the relationship between `callback` and `deps`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the linter complains about the deps or the callback if you don't declare your useEffect callback inline like so:

```
const useNonNullEffect = (callback: () => void, deps: any[]) => {
  const fn = () => {
    if(deps.some(dep => dep === null)){
      return
    }
    return callback()
  }
  useEffect(fn, deps)
}
```

Not sure if it's intentional or if the behavior might change in the future, but for now if you check the problems tab in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/relaxed-golick-c6v3z) there should be 0 linting problems reported.